# BGE: Getting keyboard entries on screen, entered characters are black

Tags: python, game-engine

In an application I would like to get a gamer's name to use it later in my Python code. So far I am using "Dynamic Text Display" as shown in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKO4jfAHtjk. I find the procedure pretty complicated. In an older version of the appliction it worked, but now I get only black boxes instead.

[image: Old version][image: New version]

I made a lot of changes and don't know where I lost it. In the object I check I think everything according to the clip above. Still all black.

Then I tried to get the name from the keyboard events, but since I am using a german keyboard I run into trouble with our special characters. It seems that the program assumes an US keyboard. I even thought about changing the bge.events. EventToString() method to cover my keyboard type, or create a new one based on it. But I did not find the source code.

Any ideas? I prefer a Python solution based on the keyboard events, getting the keyboard events right.

Answer (score 2):

Text objects are supported in the latest versions of blender (have been for a while now).

Example .blend (start game and type): http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32301

By default, "BFont" is used, but you can set other TTF fonts, as you would normally for blender, and those should also work.

Comment: Way better, very simple compared to the youtube procedure. But now the special character (ß, ä, ü, ö) issue comes up again, because an US keyboard is assumed. I think I will fix that in Python.

Comment: I found out that the problem is the console output we are using to debug the programme. On Windows the special characters (ß, ä, ö, ü, Ä, Ö, Ü) do not come out correctly, even though ord() of the character is the correct ASCII code (http://web.forret.com/tools/charmap.asp?show=ascii). So that is not a problem in my application. The only issue is that the upper umlaute (Ä, Ö, Ü) come out as A, O, U. Well, for me that is good enough. Case closed. Thank you.